# No executable found matching command "nuget"

Tags: nuget

While compiling the project it throws the error as follows

```
Error       No executable found matching command "nuget"
```

I also added a postcompile script in my project.json file as

```
"scripts": { "postcompile": [ "nuget pack project.json -outputdirectory f:\\foo" ] }
```

I have kept the nuget.exe on that path.

Comment: Did you place the location of nuget.exe in your PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Add nuget.exe in your path variable. Go to System Properties-Environment Variables->System Variables. Then edit the path variable and add the path where you kept nuget.exe to that variable with prefix of ;